# iOS YTPlayerview doesn't load embed video while Android Player API does

Tags: ios, uiwebview, ytplayerview, embedded-video, ytplayer

I am currently working on an iOS application that is displaying video highlights for football matches. Some of our embedded videos are working successfully, however some videos display this error message. [Error Message Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwQuW.png)

The same videos that are unavailable on iOS are available on our Android application using the equivalent Android Player API, is it possible that the different platforms have different embedding permissions? Or does anybody have any suggestions to resolve the issue?